# Transform function not working in styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to change the styled of "IconRadioButtonRound" component based on the "HiddenCheckBox" value.I am able to change the bakcground of "IconRadioButtonRound" with same prop i.e."checked" but not able to transform it. Please help me solve this!

Styled components:

```
export const HiddenCheckbox = styled.input.attrs({ type: 'checkbox' })`
  transform: scale(8);
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
`;

export const IconRadioButtonRound = styled.button`
  width: 63px;
  height: 62px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: ${props =>
    props.checked ? '4px solid #daa520' : '1px solid #daa520'};
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 500ms linear;
  background: ${props => (props.checked ? 'rgba(66, 226, 248, 0.3)' : 'white')};
  transform: translateY(${props => (props.checked ? '-15px' : '0')});
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
`;
```

Component where I am using it

```
 <IconCheckBoxRoundButton>
                  <HiddenCheckbox
                    key={index}
                    name={item.itemName}
                    value={item.itemName}
                    onChange={e => handleAddOnItemChange(e)}
                  />
                  <IconCheckBoxRound checked={item.isChecked}>
                    <CheckBoxIcon src={item.itemIconURL} />
                  </IconCheckBoxRound>
                  <InputLabel
                    for={item.itemName}
                    style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}
                    lineHeight="18px"
                  >
                    <CheckBoxIconName>
                      <PTSansText fontSize="18px" lineHeight="18px">
                        {item.itemName}
                      </PTSansText>
                    </CheckBoxIconName>
                    <CheckBoxIconName>
                      <PTSansText fontSize="16px">
                        <span>Rs. </span>
                        {item.itemPrice}
                      </PTSansText>
                    </CheckBoxIconName>
                  </InputLabel>
                </IconCheckBoxRoundButton>
```

Comment: Not sure it's the only issue here but you don't pass the `checked` prop to the `<IconCheckBoxRoundButton>` component.

Comment: `transition: 500ms linear;` remove  `transform`

Comment: Yes that was the issue.. Thank I was not passing checked prop..:-(

Comment: @sgrmhdk I've done the same many times and know the pain :(